# Json or Excel complete enterprise taxonomy file

Tags: json, excel, taxonomy

I need a json or excel taxonomy file which has complete enterprise term set  (in a hierarchical order). Any other format is also fine as far as I will be able to generate a json using that format. Please note this is not about sharepoint taxonomy. I need a predefined term set to use offline. I don't want to use a online web service or other APIs. I need this file to create my own API. I am looking for a free one but i am ready to pay otherwise. Is there any resources? I know that this is not a programming question. But I am asking it here because you might have used one for your projects. And I spent days on internet on searching and posting on other sites. I am not able to find a proper resource yet. Please help me. Thanks in advance.